# Convert a java-script code in to a java class

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I am new to javascript and want to convert a javascript model into a java class

This is for my commerce app. and I wanted to generate and store a cart for my client side (Android app).

javascript code

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCrart) {
  this.items = oldCrart.items || {}; //if oldcart doesnot exist use empity as default
  this.totalQty = oldCrart.totalQty || 0;
  this.totalPrice = oldCrart.totalPrice || 0;

  this.add = function(item, id) {
    var storedItem = this.items[id];
    if (!storedItem) {
      storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, qty: 0, price: 0 };
    }
    storedItem.qty++;
    storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
    this.totalQty++;
    this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price * 1;
  };
  this.generateArray = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var id in this.items) {
      arr.push(this.items[id]);
    }
    return arr;
  };
};
```

here is my cart.java

```
public class Cart {

    List<Items> items;
    int totalQty,qty=0;
    double totalPrice, price;


    public Cart(List<String> items, int totalQty, double totalPrice) {
        this.items = items;
        this.totalQty = totalQty;
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

   public void add(List<String> items, String id){
        String storedItem = this.items[id];

        if(!storedItem){
            storedItem=this.items[id;

        }
        qty++;
        price= items.price * qty;
        totalQty++;
        totalPrice=item.price * 1;


   }


}
```

This is generated by the backend and I want the client side to generate an equivalent output. Thank you

```
{"items":{"5c921268bccaaebc228cee58":{"item":{
    "_id":"5c921268bccaaebc228cee58","pname":"phone case","price":"123",
    "image":"img.jpg",
    "stokeamount":20,
    "description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
     sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      ","__v":0,
      "tags":[],
      "rating":{"five":0,"four":0,"three":0,"two":0,"one":0,"averge":0},
      "department":{"department":"electronics","new":true,"colors":[]},
      "comments":[],"view":"80",
      "manufacture":
      [{"manufacturer":"adulis","_id":"5c921268bccaaebc228cee59"}]},
      "qty":1,"price":123}},"totalQty":1,"totalPrice":123}
```

Comment: and what is a problem?

Comment: I want a Java class that generates the same output as you can see above

Comment: that is not a problem. That is what you want. The problem is that stops you from doing what you want.

Comment: i need help on creating the java class, man

Comment: if `i need help on creating the java class` means you want somebody to do it instead of you, then it is not called `help`, it is called `work` which has to be payed. But if you really need help - you need to tell which kind of help you want, and what exactly in that code is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library for this.

add this to gradle: `implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2"`

Then create new Gson instance: `Gson mGson = new Gson();`

Now the data that comes from the server is String in format of Json so you can generate custom class like this: `Cart cart = mGson.fromJson(cartStringJson, Cart.class);`

Make sure that all property names are same in your java class as in you javascript data, else they will be omitted, also property types must be correct.

Comment: But I am already using retrofit to get API data and GsonConverterFactory to parse JSON data

Comment: I need help on creating the java class that is equivalent to the javascript